# Rao blackwell theorem but the unbiased estimator is a function of the sufficient statistic

Tags: unbiased-estimator, sufficient-statistics, rao-blackwell

The Rao-Blackwell Theorem states the following:

Let $T(\mathbf X)$ be a sufficient statistic for the statistical model $(S, \{f_{\theta}: \theta \in \Theta\})$ and $\hat \theta(\mathbf X)$ be and unbiased estimator for the parameter $\theta \in \Theta \subseteq \Bbb R^k$. Define $$\theta^*(T(\mathbf X))= \Bbb E_{\theta}[\hat \theta (\mathbf X) | T(\mathbf X)]$$ .

The conditional expectation is independent of $\theta$, i.e.$$\theta^*(T\mathbf X))= \Bbb E[\hat \theta(\mathbf X) | T(\mathbf X)]$$

i.e $\theta^*(\mathbf X)$ is an estimator. Furthermore, the estimator $\theta^*(\mathbf x)$ is unbiased with variance smaller than that of $\hat \theta (\mathbf X)$ i.e

$$1. \Bbb E_{\theta}[\theta^*(\mathbf X)]= \theta, \forall \theta \in \Theta$$

$$2.Cov_{\theta}\theta^*(\mathbf X) \leq Cov_{\theta} \hat \theta (\mathbf X)$$

So, my question is, what happens if $\hat \theta (\mathbf X)$ is a function of the sufficient statistic $T(\mathbf X)$? Is $\theta^*(\mathbf X)$ equal to the $\hat \theta(\mathbf X)$? And if so, why?

The reason I think they're equal is because their variances are equal. But is that true? I mean if the variances are equal does it necessarily mean the estimators are equal?

Comment: If $\hat\theta=g(T)$ for some $g$ then $E[\hat\theta\mid T]=g(T)$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom So the two estimators are not equal?

Comment: @StubbornAtom oh, wait, i think i figured it out. Since $\hat \theta (\mathbf X)$ is a function of $T(\mathbf X)$, then $\Bbb E[\hat \theta (\mathbf X)  | T(\mathbf X)]= \hat \theta (\mathbf X) $ ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said before. The estimator remains unchanged if it is a function of $T$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Okay, thanks. Last question: Can I state that $\theta^*(X)= \hat \theta(x)$ or if $\hat \theta (X)= g(T(X))$ for some $g$ then $\theta^*(X) = g(T(X))$? I mean is there really any difference?

Comment: I don't understand what you are really asking, but looks like you are complicating things.